# Creating a responsive, sliding hero section on the landing page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem creating a sliding hero section on a landing page on a project I'm working on, I'm using html. CSS and JavaScript, I have tried many way but it doesn't come about how I need it to, any help towards this will be really of help, to be specific I'm using vanilla JavaScript

Comment: Please show the code for your *best* result - that way, we'll know what you're trying to do, and what you're doing wrong.

Comment: This is the sort of question a search engine can answer perfectly well. But here’s a [link](https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/) to get you started.